# Multiple Hangfire Recurring jobs can't be scheduled in DotNet 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, cron, asp.net-core-webapi, hangfire

I have some hangfire jobs (10 jobs in total) in the asp dotNet core application. I keep adding until its ten. 4 of the run only once a week, and one runs every 5mins. Then others run at specific times during the day. I have recreated the hangfire jobs several times. it might run smoothly for, say, 45 mins and stop.

Before now, I have four jobs that have been running smoothly.

But now I am always getting this error on the ones running every 5 mins.

I tried this fix but didn't work
https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/pull/502#issuecomment-176744750

**Modified**
The app is deployed on Azure Appservice

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Recurring job can't be scheduled, see inner exception for details.
 ---> Hangfire.Common.JobLoadException: Could not load the job. See inner exception for the details.
 ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type BackgroundJobs.ProcessAndSendNotifications' from assembly 'PortCall.Info, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(QCallAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type, ObjectHandleOnStack keepAlive, ObjectHandleOnStack assemblyLoadContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at Hangfire.Common.TypeHelper.TypeResolver(Assembly assembly, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at System.TypeNameParser.ResolveType(Assembly assembly, String[] names, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.TypeNameParser.ConstructType(Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.TypeNameParser.GetType(String typeName, Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError)
   at Hangfire.Common.TypeHelper.DefaultTypeResolver(String typeName)
   at Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.DeserializeJob()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.DeserializeJob()
   at Hangfire.RecurringJobEntity..ctor(String recurringJobId, IDictionary`2 recurringJob, ITimeZoneResolver timeZoneResolver, DateTime now)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Hangfire.Server.RecurringJobScheduler.ScheduleRecurringJob(BackgroundProcessContext context, IStorageConnection connection, String recurringJobId, RecurringJobEntity recurringJob, DateTime now)
```

startup.cs

```
            services.AddHangfire(h =>
            {
                h.UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Connection"));
            });
           
            services.AddHangfireServer();
.......
......
     app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
            app.UseHangfireDashboard("/scheduler");

  RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<Jobs>("Mondays", UserReportJobs => Jobs.CruiseReport(), "0 6 * * MON");
....
....
....
```

Comment: Hangfire job methods need to be public, are they?

Comment: Yes the methods are public

Comment: Can you give detail on the link between `BackgroundJobs.ProcessAndSendNotifications`, `Jobs`, `Jobs.CruiseReport` ? Why isn't the scheduling something like `RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<Jobs>("Mondays", userReportJobs => userReportJobs.CruiseReport(), "0 6 * * MON");` 
I guess Hangfire tries to instantiate a `ProcessAndSendNotifications` instance as `Jobs` because of a DI binding somewhere